# Deduce datatype based on the input datatype in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there a way to deduce the datatype from the input to the function in C++?

Example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
func(T input){
    if((std::is_same<T, float>::value))
        uint32_t compute;
    else if((std::is_same<T, double>::value))
        uint64_t compute;

    // rest of the function which uses compute value to do necessary computation.
}
```

I understand with the current declaration, the scope of the variable dies after the `if` condition loop. So I have added a `func_compute` and calling it from each `if` condition.

I wanted to know, is there a way to do it in a much cleaner way?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
void func(T input)
{
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_same<T, float>::value,
        std::uint32_t,
        typename std::conditional<
            std::is_same<T, double>::value,
            std::uint64_t,
            void
        >::type
    >::type compute;
    std::cout << sizeof compute << '\n';
}

int main(void)
{
    func(1.23);
    func(1.23f);
//  func(1); // error: variable or field 'compute' declared void
}
```

Possible output:

```
8
4
```

Comment: Or, in C++14 and later, `std::conditional_t` and `std::is_same_v`, which will clean up that declaration a bit more

Answer (score 1):

C++17's [`constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is very suitable for your case. If you don’t mind using C++17 (although I strongly doubt it), there is a much cleaner way:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T> 
void func(T input){
  auto compute = [] {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
      return std::uint32_t{};
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
      return std::uint64_t{};
  }();

  // rest of the function which uses compute value to do necessary computation.
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/PY6YvW9TW)